# Using Handlers in remote service

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, aidl

Let's imagine we have a simple Android application, which connects to a remote service via IPC, schedules a relatively long task, then continues working while awaiting for callback with some results. AIDL interfaces:

**IRemoteService.aidl**

```java
package com.var.testservice;
import com.var.testservice.IServCallback;

interface IRemoteService {

    void scheduleHeavyTask(IServCallback callback);

}
```

**IRemoteService.aidl**

```java
package com.var.testservice;

interface IServCallback {

    void onResult(int result);

}
```

Code for activity:

```java
package com.var.testclient;

import com.var.testservice.IServCallback;
import com.var.testservice.IRemoteService;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "TestClientActivity"; 

    private IServCallback.Stub servCallbackListener = new IServCallback.Stub(){
        @Override
        public void onResult(int result) throws RemoteException {
            Log.d(TAG, "Got value: " + result);
        }

};

private ServiceConnection servConnection = new ServiceConnection(){

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
        service = IRemoteService.Stub.asInterface(binder);          
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        service = null;         
    }

    };

    private IRemoteService service;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(!bindService(new Intent(IRemoteService.class.getName()), servConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)){
            Log.d(TAG, "Service binding failed");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service binding successful");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if(service != null) {
            unbindService(servConnection);
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View view){
        Log.d(TAG, "Button click");
        if(service != null){
            try {
                service.scheduleHeavyTask(servCallbackListener);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Oops! Can't schedule task!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Code for service:

```java
package com.var.testservice;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;

public class TestService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "TestService";

    class TestServiceStub extends IRemoteService.Stub {

        private IServCallback servCallback;
        //These 2 fields will be used a bit later
        private Handler handler;
        private int result;

        //The simpliest implementation. In next snippets I will replace it with
        //other version
        @Override
        public void scheduleHeavyTask(IServCallback callback)
                    throws RemoteException {
            servCallback = callback;
            result = doSomethingLong();
            callback.onResult(result);
        }

        private int doSomethingLong(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                return 42;
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return new TestServiceStub();
    }

}
```

This version, while being really dumb (it makes UI thread from application hang for 5 seconds, causing ANR), it successfully executes all calls via IPC, delivering result to activity.
Problems start if I try to put calculations into separate thread:

```java
@Override
public void scheduleHeavyTask(IServCallback callback)
        throws RemoteException {
    servCallback = callback;
    Runnable task = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            result = doSomethingLong();
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Sending result!");
                servCallback.onResult(result);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
    new Thread(task).start();
}
```

In this case the callback is just not delivered to activity: service successfully calls `servCallback.onResult(result);`, but nothing is called within activity. No exceptions, no clues, no survivors: perfect invocation murder. I couldn't find any information about possible cause of such behavior, so I'd be grateful if someone could clarify what happens here. My suggestion's that there's some kind of security mechanism, tracking which exact threads were bound, and ignoring "unsafe" calls from other threads (something similar happens when we try to mess with UI elements from non-UI thread), but I can't be sure.

The most obvious solution is to post callback invocation to the bound thread, so I made this:

```java
@Override
public void scheduleHeavyTask(IServCallback callback)
        throws RemoteException {
    Log.d(TAG, "Schedule request received.");
    servCallback = callback;
    if(Looper.myLooper() == null) {
        Looper.prepare();
    }

    handler = new Handler();
    Runnable task = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            result = doSomethingLong();
            Log.d(TAG, "Posting result sender");
            handler.post(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Sending result!");
                        servCallback.onResult(result);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Looper.myLooper().quit();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Looper stopped");
                }

            });
        }

    };
    new Thread(task).start();
    Looper.loop();
}
```

Here I faced 2 more problems:

1. I had to call `Looper.loop()` to enable processing of callback runnables, but it blocks IPC, so I have the same result as in the beginning - no actual multithreading;
2. Registering for callback second time (after first cycle finished and returned value) results in exception:

   ```java
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.os.Handler) sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage
   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime
   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed
   at android.os.Handler.post
   at com.var.testservice.TestService$TestServiceStub$1.run
   at java.lang.Thread.run
   ```

This lefts me completely puzzled: I make a fresh instance from actual `Looper`, how can it point to dead thread?

The whole idea of service being able of queueing tasks and making callbacks when they finish doesn't sound insane to me, so I hope someone more experienced could explain me:

1. Why can't I actually make IPC calls from different threads?
2. What's wrong with my `Handler`?
3. What instruments/architecture should I use to make a clean, proper queue mechanism, so it could call IPC methods on the right thread without constantly calling `Looper.loop()`/`Looper.quit()`?

Thank you.

Comment: a more concise question would have been easier to follow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain why your program isn't working. But the version involving threads and an asynchronous callback:

```
@Override
public void scheduleHeavyTask(IServCallback callback)
        throws RemoteException {
    servCallback = callback;
    Runnable task = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            result = doSomethingLong();
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Sending result!");
                servCallback.onResult(result);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
    new Thread(task).start();
}
```

should work just fine.

Here's how Android arranges threads for AIDL and other types of Binder transaction.

- If the caller and the callee are in the same process, it becomes a simple method call. So, you should fine that `scheduleHeavyTask` is called from the very same thread as `onButtonClick`. Similarly, you should fine that the call to `onResult` should be a simple method call, from the thread running the task.
- If the caller and callee are in different processes, Android will run the Binder transactions from a pool of threads within the callee process (they are called Binder #1 etc.) Even here it's quite clever - so if `onButtonClick` called `scheduleHeavyTask` which called back to `onResult` from the same thread, then `onButtonClick` would appear directly to call `onResult` within the caller process.

There are absolutely no mechanisms to avoid calls from "unsafe" or "unbound" threads - so this simple approach you posted *should* work. As you say, it's a common pattern, and I've used it lots of times. I'd therefore recommend proceeding with this rather than fiddling with extra loopers and handlers.

Here are some ideas:

- Run it in a debugger. Assuming your service and activity are in the same process, you should be able to set breakpoints and see sensible method calls taking place.
- Even if you can't, fire up `ddms` from the command line, or show the Devices and Threads views within Eclipse. This will give you a view of exactly what each thread is doing - you can get a callstack. It's normally possible to use this even in cases where a full-on debugger would be inconvenient.
- Do you have the word `synchronized` anywhere? What could be happening is that `onResult` wants to go ahead and run, but it's blocked on some monitor. As soon as it becomes unblocked, it might well run.

Comment: @Dimetry I assume that you got this to work. What was it that was causing onResult(int ) not to be called in your activities callback?